# How to clear the animation which has already run or are running in background

Tags: android, animation

switching between different RelativeLayouts like panel1,2,3 etc and running animations in them using imageviews  like`img.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_14);
                    img.setY(-500);
                    AnimatorSet an14 = new AnimatorSet();
                    an14.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img38, Y, -500f, -40f));
                    an14.setStartDelay(11000);
                    an14.setDuration(900);
                    an14.start();`
but when I re switch to old panel the animations are not visible,i tried 
img.clearAmnimation();panel.clearAnimation();
but this doesn't work,i'm new in animation kindly guide

Comment: "Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." is what showing in Logcat, thus facing memory leaks bcz using same thread for all animations.i tried using even more thread but same prob persists.any solution for this problem